# Visualize weights of stacked Autoencoder

Tags: python, matlab, stacked, autoencoder, visualize

I trained a stacked Autoencoder. The dimension of weight of first hidden layer is ( SizeHiddenLayer1 x SizeInputLayer) so visualization of this weight is simple because the size of input data and columns of this weight are the same. but the dimension of weight of second hidden layer is (SizeHiddenLayer2 x SizeHiddenLayer1). Can anybody help me in visualizing this weight?
(In the Python or Matlab)

Comment: Have you tried anything? At least a [mcve] would help.

Comment: No, I couldn't do anything because I obtained a weight for second layer which size is (1000x x 1000) but the size of orginal input is 784.